# Read Date Format in PHP EXCEL

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have read excel file using PHP excel .

But that excel file contain some date (time format) PHP excel return wrong values for that case

My code is in below

```
enter code hereinclude 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'index.xlsx';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME)
        . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
        NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

    foreach ($rowData[0] as $k => $v)
        echo "Row: " . $row . "- Col: " . ($k + 1) . " = " . $v . "<br />";
}
```

any one can help for this..
Have some specific function for this case in PHPExcel..

My input excel file  is in below

2013-12-12,
2013-12-13

My output is in below

41621,
41631

Have some method to covert date format output data?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you read xls file with PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5 lib, the data in file is 39984, but Excel formats it using a date formatting mask as '2009-06-20'?

Excel holds dates as a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (on Windows 1900 calendar). PHPExcel stores its dates in the same way, but doesn't automatically format them for you.

You can format them yourself using `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString(39984,PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY)` 
 or any of the other format masks in 
`PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat`
, or convert it to a PHP date using 
`PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(39984)` and then use PHP's `date()` 
function to format it as you wish

Example:

```
$val = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue()));
```

Comment: Hm, this text says that "Excel holds dates as a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (on Windows 1900 calendar). PHPExcel stores its dates in the same way, but doesn't automatically format them for you."

Comment: @pnuts Yes, as it appears I should agree with you. You want to say, 41621, 41631 are not conrrect values, right ?

Comment: @pnuts i posted an answer

Comment: @pnuts no, is for you? you asked "What dates then do 41621 and 41631 represent? – pnuts Sep 17 '15 at 8:26"

Comment: como le hago para que salga el año completo?

Answer (score 22):

An other way is using gmdate:

```
$excel_date = 43010; //here is that value 41621 or 41631
$unix_date = ($excel_date - 25569) * 86400;
$excel_date = 25569 + ($unix_date / 86400);
$unix_date = ($excel_date - 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $unix_date);

//result is 2017-10-02
```

Comment: This worked for me... can you explain how this works?

Comment: @user4272288 No idea how you did it, but you saved my day, thank you stranger from 2017

Answer (score 9):

To retrieve the date you have to convert from Excel Timestamp to Linux Timestamp.
What you need to know is:

- Excel express dates in **days** while Linux do it in **seconds**.
- Excel start to count from year 1900 while Linux do it from year 1970.
- All timestamps are in GM (greenwitch meantime), so you **should not** convert it with `gmdate();` but instead use just `date();`

So, in order to convert from Excel to Linux you have to:

- remove 70 years of days: `25569`
- multiply for seconds in a day: `86400`

This is the code:

```
function fromExcelToLinux($excel_time) {
    return ($excel_time-25569)*86400;
}

$linux_time = fromExcelToLinux(30637); 
echo date("Y-m-d",$linux_time);
//should print 1983-11-17
```

That's all the folks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel_reader for excel import, You can use Code like this.

```
include('excel_reader/xlsxreader/simplexlsx.class.php');
$xlsx_class = new SimpleXLSX();
$j['IST_Time'] = '43010';
echo date('Y-m-d',$xlsx_class->unixstamp($j['IST_Time'])); // Result will be 2017-10-02
```

And For Time

```
$j['IST_Time'] = '0.416666666667'; 
echo date('h:i A',$xlsx_class->unixstamp($j['IST_Time'])); //10:00 AM
```

or view simplexlsx.class.php

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you used the PHPExcel library, and within that library, there is a function call `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()` to convert the date values. This function can be utilized to extract the desired result.

```php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'index.xlsx';

// Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME)
        . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

// Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

// Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    // Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

    foreach ($rowData[0] as $k => $v) {
        if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($k, $row))) {
            $dateValue = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($k, $row)->getValue();
            $timestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($dateValue);
            $formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
            echo "Row: " . $row . "- Col: " . ($k + 1) . " = " . $formattedDate . "<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Row: " . $row . "- Col: " . ($k + 1) . " = " . $v . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

I added a check using `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()` to determine if a cell contains a date value. If it does, I retrieve the raw date value using `$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($k, $row)->getValue()`. Then, I convert the Excel date value to a PHP timestamp using `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()`. Finally, I format the timestamp to the desired format using `date()`.

This will output the dates in the format 'Y-m-d'.